# When fputs is used directly for writing character array in a file, a different format of text is stored

Tags: c

When I used `fputs()` to directly store a character array in a file, it stored this in the file:

```
ÈLwìþ(
```

Why was that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *p;
    p=fopen("pa.txt","w+");
    char name[100];
    printf("Enter a string :");
    fputs(name,p);
    fclose(p);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I take input in name using `scanf()` or `gets()`, the correct text is stored but when directly use `fputs()` is used it stored in an unusual format.
Why does this happen?

Comment: You mean "why does accessing an uninitialized variable lead to unexpected consequences"?

Comment: Are you confusing `fgets()` with `fputs()`?

Comment: @Mr.Llama ,yes I am not able to understand it .

Comment: @chux  no I am not confused between fgets() and fputs() .

Comment: See also [Why `gets()` is so dangerous it should never be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I take input in name using `scanf()` or `gets()` correct text is stored but when directly `fputs()` is used it stored in unusual format. Why this happens ?

You haven't read the data from `stdin` before writing it out using `fputs`.

Use:

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

and then:

```
fputs(name, p);
```

Comment: I also don't understand when I compile and run this code it asks for input and takes input when I don't use scanf() or gets() .

Comment: @ameyCU, the input is processed by `getchar()`, which reads just one character. The rest are discarded since the program terminates after that.

Answer (score 2):

> When I take input in name using scanf() or gets() correct text is
>   stored but when directly fputs() is used it stored in unusual format.
>   Why this happens ?

Accessing uninitialized variable `p` is [*undefined behaviour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as its value *indeterminate* as per C standard. There's no explanation for *why* it happens. Just don't do that.

**6.7.9 Initialization, (C11 draft)**

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

And *indeterminate* is defined as:

> 3.19.2 indeterminate
>   value either an unspecified value or a trap representation

Note that function `gets()` has been removed from the recent C standard (C11) and it has never been a safe anyway due to its buffer overflow issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have opened *char* array but you haven't used it. Analyze the code you will understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[100];

    FILE *p;

    p=fopen("pa.txt","w+");

    if(!p) {
        perror("Error writing");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter a string :");
    scanf("%s",name);
    fputs(name,p);

    fclose(p);

    return 0;
}
```